# Изменение размера элемента

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Нужно сделать знак плюса в квадрате 22 на 22 пикселя, как можно увеличить знак, чтобы квадратный `<div>` с рамками, в котором он лежит, сохранил свой размер? Иными словами нужно растянуть знак плюса на всю ширину родителя. Пробовал через `font-size`, но так получается совсем не то. Искал готовый знак, чтобы вставить, но не нашёл, хоть с макета вырезай. Сам код, который имеется

```
<div class="plus_in_kvadro"><span>+</span></div>


.plus_in_kvadro{
border: 1px solid #979bac;
width: 22px;
height: 22px;
color: #979bac;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте Font Awesome:

```
<i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Взято [отсюда](http://fontawesome.ru/icon/plus/). С тегом `<i>` можете вытворять всё, что душе угодно :)

Comment: большое спасибо)

Comment: @KirillBulgakov большое пожалуйста :)